# How can I assign modal form component opening function to any another button component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 components: `ModalForm` and `BookCard`. The `ModalForm` is supposed to be put inside of the `BookCard`. When you put the `ModalForm` - it creates new button and functionates as it has to. But what if instead of creating new button I want to assign `ModalForm`'s functionality to already existing button?

**BookCard.js**

```
const BookCard = ({id, name, cover, description, price, count, loadResponse}) => {
    return (
        <Card>
            //some code
            <ModalForm /*some props*/ />
            <button className="edit-button"> // <- the button, I want to be assigned to be opening modal
                <box-icon name='edit-alt'/>
            </button>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

**ModalForm.js**

```
const ModalForm = ({/*some props*/}) => {
    //some code
    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={handleClickOpen} /> // <- the button that is being shown instead of the wanted one
            //some code    
        </div>   
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its looks like you need to handle the logic in the most up component in your case BookCard.
So ModalForm has some props like `isOpen` in BookCard you need state like `isModalOpened` and then add callback `onClick` that change `state (isModalOpened)` and then react pass that prop(isOpen) to your `ModalForm`.